# Select where column is null or not in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables with names and a schedule of dates related to those names.  I am trying to get a list of all names that have never been scheduled or have not been scheduled in the last 2 months.

```
   SELECT n.name, MAX(s.date) 
     FROM names n
LEFT JOIN schedule s ON n.id = s.nameid
    WHERE s.nameid IS NULL 
       OR s.nameid NOT IN (SELECT nameid 
                             FROM schedule 
                            WHERE date > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
 GROUP BY n.id
```

When I run this query MySQL takes over the CPU and doesn't respond.

When I change it to either of these I get results, but only half the results I am looking for:

```
   SELECT n.name, MAX(s.date) 
     FROM names n
LEFT JOIN schedule s ON n.id = s.nameid
    WHERE s.nameid IS NULL
 GROUP BY n.id

   SELECT n.name, MAX(s.date) 
     FROM names n
LEFT JOIN schedule s ON n.id = s.nameid
    WHERE s.nameid NOT IN (SELECT nameid 
                             FROM schedule 
                            WHERE date > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
 GROUP BY n.id
```

I am not sure how to get this query working to return all the results or why it takes over the CPU.

Comment: Why don't you just `union` them together?

Comment: Be aware that LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is only faster on MySQL if the columns compared can not be NULL: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OR` is a notorious poor performer, in every database I can think of.  A `UNION` if often a better alternative:

```
   SELECT n.name, MAX(s.date) 
     FROM names n
LEFT JOIN schedule s ON n.id = s.nameid
    WHERE s.nameid IS NULL
 GROUP BY n.id
UNION
   SELECT n.name, MAX(s.date) 
     FROM names n
LEFT JOIN schedule s ON n.id = s.nameid
    WHERE s.nameid NOT IN (SELECT nameid 
                             FROM schedule 
                            WHERE date > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
 GROUP BY n.id
```

`UNION` will remove duplicates -- if there's no concern about duplicates, use `UNION ALL` (it's faster, because it doesn't remove duplicates).

Additionally, the latter query has criteria against the OUTER JOIN'd table in the WHERE clause -- this criteria is applied *after* the JOIN.  You might get different results using:

```
   SELECT n.name, MAX(s.date) 
     FROM names n
LEFT JOIN schedule s ON s.nameid = n.id
                    AND s.nameid NOT IN (SELECT nameid 
                                           FROM schedule 
                                          WHERE date > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
 GROUP BY n.id
```

In the example above, the criteria will be applied *before* the OUTER JOIN.  For INNER JOINs, this can be ignored -- criteria in either spot is equivalent.

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the help.  Not sure why I didn't think of UNION but it was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your full schema, is there something wrong with

```
   SELECT n.name, max(s.date)
     FROM names n
LEFT JOIN schedule s 
       ON n.id = s.nameid
    WHERE s.nameid IS NULL
       OR s.date <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
 GROUP BY n.id
```

Comment: This can return results different from the OP's intention (judging by their query). Your query would merely exclude rows that are over 2 months old, but the OP's version would exclude *items* that are found among 2+ month old rows (and might be found among newer rows too, yet would still be excluded).